Telethon magic secret
I get confused when trying to generate an XLSX report from the database. Everything works fine when I use a simple list, but when I create a list from a database query, the Telethon method slices my values. Here is the code that is working:
@shared_task
def get_telegram_data() -> List:
    client = TelegramClient('test_session', TELEGRAM_API_ID, TELEGRAM_API_HASH)

    chat_ids = [-1001830160445, -1002011482715]

    data = []

    client.start(bot_token=TELEGRAM_BOT_API_TOKEN)

    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        client.send_code_request(TELEGRAM_BOT_API_TOKEN)

    for chat_id in chat_ids:
        entity = client.get_entity(chat_id)
        users = client.get_participants(entity)

        for user in users:
            data.append([user.id, user.username, user.first_name, user.last_name])

    client.disconnect()

    return data

But when i switch the chat_ids values from list to a query:
chat_ids = list(map(int, CarDepartment.objects
                                      .values_list('chat_id', flat=True)
                                      .distinct()))

I get the following error:

ValueError at /admin/bot/taxiemployee/download_telegram_users_report/
Could not find the input entity for PeerChannel(channel_id=1971623109) (PeerChannel).

The most interesting thing is that the types are the same:
chat_ids = [-1001830160445, -1002011482715]
    print(
        type(chat_ids),
        type(chat_ids[0]),
        chat_ids[0]
    )

chat_ids = list(map(int, CarDepartment.objects
                                      .values_list('chat_id', flat=True)
                                      .distinct()))
    print(
        type(new_chat_ids),
        type(new_chat_ids[0]),
        new_chat_ids[0]
    )

output
taxi_bot-worker-1  | <class 'list'> <class 'int'> -1001830160445
taxi_bot-worker-1  | <class 'list'> <class 'int'> -1001971623109


Looks like the content in your database does not match the chat_ids you provide in the list. The error you got indicates that for one of the chat_ids, Telethon is unable to fetch the entity. You should match the values to verify this once
